# Overriding CDbCommand->queryInternal()

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, yii, sqlsrv

An existing yii-Framework application must be migrated to using *{pdo_,}sqlsrv* to communicate with the SQL-Server Backend as the entire application is being migrated from Lunix to Windows.

There are several invocations of (immutable) stored procedures that yield multiple row sets. The legacy mssql-driver luckily ignored the former. Using sqlsrv, one has to use `sqlsrv_next_result()` on the result handle in order to avoid `SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields` and skip on to the relevant/usable rowset.

Being new to yii, I have found no way of introducing an extension to `CDbCommand` at a low enough level so that AR etc. will still function. My current solution thus directly modifies framework/library code which is obviously not an option once we go into production.

This is my modification to the library (starting in CDbCommand.php#515):

```
$retry_hack = false;
do {
        try {
                $result=$this->_statement->$method();
                $retry_hack = false;  // won't get here on throw
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
                // If we do not have any more rowsets we obviously have
                // a proper exception at this point and just re-throw
                // it to whomever wants to catch it.

                if (!($retry_hack = true === $this->_statement->nextRowset())) {
                        throw $e;
                }
        }
} while ($retry_hack);
```

Now my question: how can I introduce this behaviour at a low enough level without having to modify framework/library code?

Comment: Came across `MultipleActiveResultSets=False` which may be specified in the DSN - it does not solve the problem;